# Android DataBinding is leaking Memory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm using data-binding and I have declared a `lateinit var` for the binding and when I'm going to different fragment Leaky canary showing a leak.

**Fragment**

```
class HomeFragment : BottomNavViewHostBaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        return binding.root
    }

   ...
}
```

Here is the Info from Leaky Carny

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout has leaked:
Toast$TN.mNextView
↳ LinearLayout.mContext
↳ MainActivity.navigationView
↳ NavigationView.listener
↳ BaseFragment$setNavigationDrawerItemSelectedListener$1.this$0 (anonymous implementation of com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) ↳ OrdersHostFragment.mFragmentManager
↳ FragmentManagerImpl.mActive
↳ HashMap.table
↳ array HashMap$HashMapEntry[].[0]
↳ HashMap$HashMapEntry.value
↳ HomeFragment.!(binding)!
↳ FragmentHomeBindingImpl.!(mboundView0)!
↳ ConstraintLayout
```

How do I solve this and Should I need to do `binding=null` inside `onDestroyView`? But if I need to do this then what is the point of `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` then?

Comment: Why are you holding the binding? What is it useful to? Genuine question, I've always used the binding as `onCreateView` local variable.

Comment: @Agent_L There could be multiple `Views` that I need to access outside of `onCreateView` to perform actions. Like `Visibility` of a button etc.

Comment: For me, the whole point of DataBinding is to never have to access `View`s again.

Comment: @Agent_L how? Do you do all the manipulations via `ViewModel` and `Binding Adapters`?

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. No more code in `Fragment`/`Activity`.

Comment: what if get value from edittext or checkbox? @Agent_L  I have to use binding.etName.text

Comment: @Freddy two-way databinding: `android:text="@={viewmodel.something}"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to fragment [*lifecycle*](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating), `onDestroyView()` was called, but fragment is not fully destroyed - so `onDestroy()` is not called. In that case, if you don't reset binding property by hand, it references *view tree* (it's some kind of leak).

> But if I need to do this then what is the point of binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner then?

If you supply `LifecycleOwner` to binding object, it allows to observe all `LiveData` objects inside generated binding class. But it can't know about external references on `binding` instance outside (from any other classes of your project) - that's why it can't automatically reset them.

Comment: What should I do for solving it? `binding = null` in `onDestroyView`?

Comment: if referencing to a view is kind of leak, for example, an instance of TextView in my fragment is leak too? so traditional usage that defined all of the view in the top of fragment/activity is a memory-leak. so how should we access to views is OK?

Comment: @beigirad, referencing to view is not necessarily a leak. For example, if you have activity and save view in variable - it's not memory leak, GC resolves that after activity is destoryed. If you have fragment, you can use view only between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView` calls. If you can access view, after `onDestroyView` was called - it's problem. That's also actual for binding's instances.

Comment: @VarunRaj did you solve your problem? by making binding = null in onDestroyView ? I only found this solution working but I don't think it's a good approach.

Comment: @MohsenEinhesari, if you save binding in some variable in fragment, it's absolutely normal to null it by hand (as you need to do for each view stored in variable), because lifetime of fragment's **view** is less than lifetime of fragment.

Comment: @ConstOrVar I think in most cases we should store binding in a variable, right? and another thing, what does binding.unbind do? I thought it should avoid memory leak too ( like binding = null).

Comment: @MohsenEinhesari, store binding in variables is not always required - so it depends on screen's logic. [`unbind()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#unbind()) according to documentation simply removes listeners, but still have view's cached.

Comment: @MohsenEinhesari yeah it kinda did solve my problem. Then what should I do then?

Comment: @VarunRaj nothing! I was looking for a better solution but after ConstOrVar comments I think it's good enough.

Comment: Can we use WeakReference<FragmentClassDataBinding> for this, and not worry about the unbinding / setting binding = null in onDestroyView() ? ConstOrVar, @Mohsen Einhesari

Answer (score 31):

**Here is the recommended way from [google docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) to initialize and clear the binding in Fragments:**

**Kotlin:**

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

**Java:**

```
private ResultProfileBinding binding;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, 
                          ViewGroup container, 
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

Also, here is a [medium blog post](https://medium.com/default-to-open/handling-lifecycle-with-view-binding-in-fragments-a7f237c56832#:~:text=View%20Binding%20is%20an%20upcoming,be%20using%20it%20in%20Fragments.) to read to get rid of binding memory leak with Property Delegate.

Comment: Note that link refers to ViewBinding, but I assume the concept is the same with DataBinding even though I can't find a doc that says so and the samples don't nullify view references either.

Comment: Can we use `WeakReference<FragmentClassDataBinding>` for this, and not worry about the unbinding / setting binding = null in `onDestroyView()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Just call `binding.unbind()` in `onDestroyView()` method.

Comment: I cannot see any unbind method in my binding.

Comment: sorry my fault, I was using ViewBinding instead of DataBinding

Answer (score 0):

```
class FragmentViewBindingDelegate<T : ViewBinding>(
    bindingClass: Class<T>,
    private val fragment: Fragment
) : ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, T> {

    /**
     * initiate variable for binding view
     */
    private var binding: T? = null

    /**
     * get the bind method from View class
     */
    private val bindMethod = bindingClass.getMethod("bind", View::class.java)

    init {
        fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
            val viewLifecycleOwnerLiveDataObserver =
                Observer<LifecycleOwner?> {
                    val viewLifecycleOwner = it ?: return@Observer

                    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                        override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                            binding = null
                        }
                    })
                }

            override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever(viewLifecycleOwnerLiveDataObserver)
            }

            override fun onDestroy(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.removeObserver(viewLifecycleOwnerLiveDataObserver)
            }
        })
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        binding?.let { return it }


        /**
         * Checking the fragment lifecycle
         */
        val lifecycle = fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle
        if (!lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.INITIALIZED)) {
            error("Cannot access view bindings. View lifecycle is ${lifecycle.currentState}!")
        }


        /**
         * Bind layout
         */
        val invoke = bindMethod.invoke(null, thisRef.requireView()) as T

        return invoke.also { this.binding = it }
    }
}
 
inline fun <reified T : ViewBinding> Fragment.viewBinding() = FragmentViewBindingDelegate(T::class.java, this)
```

usage inside fragment:

```
  private val binding: Fragment_NAME_Binding by viewBinding()
```