# Synthetics to Viewbinding issues (onBackPress & Navigation Drawer)

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, onbackpressed, android-viewbinding

I am updating my app to completely remove synthetics and move to viewbinding, however I am struggling with converting the onBackPressed method (now also deprecated) with my Activity, Fragment and Navigation Drawer.

I originally had it like this:

**Activity (Before)**

```
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


                val activityBinding: BusinessActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                    this,
                    R.layout.business_activity
                )

                nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

                val headerView = activityBinding.navView.getHeaderView(0)
                headerView.navHeaderEmailText.setOnClickListener { sendSupportEmail() }

                navController = findNavController(this, R.id.NavHostFragment)
                
                // other stuff
            }
             
              fun openCloseNavigationDrawer() {

                if (business_drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    business_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                } else {
                    business_drawer_layout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                }
            }

            override fun onBackPressed() {

                val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.NavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
                val backStackEntryCount = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.backStackEntryCount

                when {
                    (business_drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) -> business_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(
                        GravityCompat.START
                    )

                    (backStackEntryCount == 0) -> dialogLeaveApp()

                    else -> super.onBackPressed()
                }
            }
           
           private fun dialogLeaveApp(){

                MaterialDialog(this).show {
                    title(R.string.business_activity_dialog_leave_app_heading)
                    message(R.string.business_activity_dialog_leave_app_message)
                    positiveButton(R.string.business_activity_dialog_confirm_button){
                        super.onBackPressed()
                    }
                    negativeButton(R.string.business_activity_dialog_cancel_button) {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                
            override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

                when (item.itemId) {

                    R.id.nav_sites_fragment -> navigateWithClearStack(R.id.sitesFragment)
                    R.id.nav_projects_fragment -> navigateWithClearStack(R.id.projectsFragment)
                    R.id.nav_contacts_fragment -> navigateWithClearStack(R.id.contactsFragment)
                    R.id.nav_tasks_fragment -> navigateWithClearStack(R.id.tasksFragment)

                    R.id.nav_profile_fragment -> makeToast("Todo: Profile Fragment")
                    R.id.nav_settings_fragment -> navigateWithClearStack(R.id.settingsFragment)
                }
                business_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
                return true
            }
            
                        
            private fun navigateWithClearStack(destination: Int) {
                businessViewModel.clearCurrentVMData()
                val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.NavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
                val inflater = navHostFragment.navController.navInflater
                val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.business_navigation)
                graph.startDestination = destination

                navController.graph = graph
            }


     }
```

**Fragment (already using viewbinding)**

```
    class SitesFragment : Fragment() {

        private lateinit var navController: NavController
        private lateinit var businessViewModel: BusinessViewModel
        private lateinit var sitesAdapter: SitesRecyclerViewAdapter

        private var _binding: SitesFragmentBinding? = null // this property is only valid between onCreateView & onDestroyView
        private val binding get() = _binding!! //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647751/android-databinding-is-leaking-memory

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView()")
            activity?.let {
                businessViewModel = ViewModelProvider(it).get(BusinessViewModel::class.java)
                Log.d(TAG, "businessViewModel = $businessViewModel")
            }

            Log.d(TAG, businessViewModel.currentStatus("${TAG}, onCreateView()"))

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            _binding = SitesFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val view = binding.root

            binding.apply {
            
                sitesDrawerMenuButton.setOnClickListener {
                    (activity as BusinessActivity).openCloseNavigationDrawer()
                    Log.d(TAG, "sitesDrawerMenuButton clicked, openCloseNavigationDrawer()")
                }
                
                // Other listeners

            }
            return view

        }
```

**Activity (After)**

```
      private var _binding: BusinessActivityBinding? = null
      private val binding get() = _binding!!


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            // Inflate the layout for this activity
            _binding = BusinessActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.NavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
            this.navController = navHostFragment.navController

            binding.navView.setupWithNavController(this.navController)

            // Setup OnBackPressedDispatcher
            val backPressedCallback = object:OnBackPressedCallback(false){
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    onBackButtonPressed()
                }
            }
            
            // Other stuff
            
        }
        
        fun openCloseNavigationDrawer() { // accessed by Fragment

            if (binding.businessDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                binding.businessDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            } else {
                binding.businessDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            }
        }

        fun onBackButtonPressed() {

            val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.NavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
            val backStackEntryCount = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount

            when {
                (binding.businessDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) -> binding.businessDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(
                    GravityCompat.START
                )

                (backStackEntryCount == 0) -> dialogLeaveApp()
            }
        }

        private fun dialogLeaveApp(){
        
        // as before
        
        }

        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        
        // as before

        }
              
        private fun navigateWithClearStack(destination: Int) {

        // as before

        }
```

So the issue is that when you back press, it simply exits the app, rather than triggering my function onBackButtonPressed() (which replaces the depricated onBackPressed())and variable 'backPressedCallback' is never used..

Comment: FYI, you're using the wrong "insert code" button. You're using the one for JavaScript snippets. Anyway, what are you struggling with? It looks like you removed the `else -> super.onBackPressed()` but otherwise you have the same logic. Does your problem actually have anything to do with view binding, or are you only asking how to handle back presses without the deprecated functions?

Comment: Hi Tenfour04, sorry if I have incorrectly added the code - I will lookup what I should be doing!  

So the issue is that when you back press, it simply exits the app, rather than triggering my function onBackButtonPressed() and variable 'backPressedCallback' is never used.